# Why isn't the background-image working here

Tags: html, css, image

Please check the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/BbkBf/

I got two questions: 
1. why is the background-image not working for the first one (you may say it's `a` tag is empty, but even then doesn't work).

2. why is the image not shown for the second `img` tag?

Is it some wordpress problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the domain in which the image is hosted is protected against [hotlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking), meaning they won't let you load the image from their domain unless you are inside their domain. try uploading it to a different domain.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/BbkBf/3/

Comment: I think that may be the answer, it works for me without issue. However, I am unfamiliar with wordpress.

Comment: @amosrivera any way to disable this in wordpress?

Comment: it depends on what the site is using for hotlinking protection, if it is through wordpress then there should be a installed plug in that you need to configure